# Sorting multiple lists based on two lists with precedence in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have multiple lists with the following format:

```
list_one=['2','2','1','4','4','3','5','6']
list_two=['b','a','a','a','b','b','a','a']
list_three=['1','2','3','4','5','7','9','10']
```

How can I sort all these lists by list_one and list_two such that list_one takes precedence over list_two? The output would look like this after sorting:

```
list_one=['6','5','4','4','3','2','2','1']
list_two=['a','a','a','b','b','a','b','a']
list_three=['10','9','4','5','7','2','1','3']
```

Essentially we sort by the first list and then sort by the second list still respecting the sorting done by the first list, or sorting within the sorting that was done from list one. I have seen some methods done with zip but that is usually done by sorting only with one list. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with zip:

```
list_one=['2','2','1','4','4','3','5','6']
list_two=['b','a','a','a','b','b','a','a']
list_three=['1','2','3','4','5','7','9','10']

list_one,list_two,list_three = map(list,zip(*sorted(zip(list_one,list_two,list_three),reverse=True)))

print(list_one)
print(list_two)
print(list_three)
['6', '5', '4', '4', '3', '2', '2', '1']
['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a']
['10', '9', '5', '4', '7', '1', '2', '3']
```

Applying zip to the 3 lists creates a list of tuples with the corresponding values of each list: [('6', 'a', '10'), ('5', 'a', '9'), ('4', 'b', '5'), ...

Sorting these tuples gives precedence to the first list over the second and third ones.

Applying `zip(*...)` turns the list of (sorted) tuples back into 3 big tuples corresponding to each list.  You can then reassign the 3 variables after mapping the tuples back into lists.

Another approach would be to build a list of indexes sorted using values from the first two lists and then map each list to the positions of the sorted indexes:

```
indexes = sorted(range(len(list_one)),key=lambda i:(list_one[i],list_two[i]))

list_one   = [list_one[i]   for i in indexes]
list_two   = [list_two[i]   for i in indexes]
list_three = [list_three[i] for i in indexes]
```

Comment: I'm starting to see the beauty of `zip` from this answer

Answer (score 0):

Zip the three lists in your sort order `zip(list_one, list_two, list_three)`.
Sort the triples, and then unzip into your desired targets.

Comment: How would you sort the triples? I want to sort by the stated order

Comment: Ummm ... use `sort` or `sorted`.  What didn't work when you read the documentation and tried it?